# Como faço para verificar registro em tempo real?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um sistema de cadastro que preciso verificar em tempo real se o email existe no banco de dados.

Mas o mesmo não está funcionando, na `<div id="resposta"></div>` não exibe resultado algum.

**JavaScript**

```
<script language="javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    var email = $("#email"); 
        email.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'plano.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            } 
        }); 
    }); 

        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

**plano.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailpostado = $_POST['email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM conta WHERE email = '{$emailpostado}'");

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email')); 
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Usuário valido.' )); 
}
```

Comment: Por que em vez de retornar JSON vc não faz um simples `echo`?

Comment: A resposta do Andrei está correta, mas vc pode pegar pelo `name` se não quiser adicionar um `id` no campo: `var email = $("input[name='email']");`.

Comment: @sam vou colocar dessa forma que você escreveu.

Comment: Como foi colocado na resposta do leo e citado pelo sam, no seu caso, não há necessidade de gerar um JSON no lado do cliente, nem do servidor, pois é apenas uma frase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Por que em vez de retornar JSON vc não faz um simples echo?
>
> Obs evento [**blur**](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) disparado quando o input perde o foco

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="text" id="email"/>
 <div id="resultados"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#email').blur(function() {
        $th = $(this);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'plano.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email: $th.val()},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Carregando...");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#resultados").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#resultados").html("Ouve um erro ao enviar sua URL");
            }
         });//ajax       
    });
});

</script>
```

**plano.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NOME_DB',"USUARIO","SENHA");

    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT email FROM conta where email='$email'");
    $sql->execute();

    $linha = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $emailBanco = $linha['email'];

    echo $emailBanco;
    echo "<br>";

    if(isset($email ) && $emailBanco === $email ){
        echo "Este email existe no banco";
    }else{
        echo "Email digitado " .$emailBanco. " Nao existe no banco "; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está tentando pegar o id "email" que não existe. Essa linha gera um erro:

```
var email = $("#email");
```

Você precisa inserir o id no seu `<input/>`:

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Email">
```

Se você quiser pegar o valor do `name`. Você pode pega-lo assim:

```
var email = $("input[name='email']");
```

Quando acontecer coisas inesperadas como essa, você pode apertar **F12** ir em console e verificar os erros que estão ocorrendo.